# iOS App redirects first to Facebook app, then Safari, instead of Single Sign On

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iOS app where it used to login with Facebook correctly using the Single sign-on mechanism. I've just added an extra required permission (`user_likes`) and now when a previously registered user tries to login with Facebook, they are first redirected to Facebook app, and from there, a Safari Facebook login window appears, creating an unpleasant user experience. I don't know if it's related to my new permission or Facebook's ever changing login policies. Why would that happen, and how can I correct this behavior? I haven't changed anything at Facebook developers portal, and both Single Sign-on and Deep Linking are enabled, with the correct App ID.

Here is my code for logging in:

```
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:TanisalimFacebookReadPermissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:handler];
```

My read permissions are defined as: `#define TanisalimFacebookReadPermissions @[@"user_photos", @"user_friends", @"user_birthday", @"user_likes"]`

When I call the open active session code above, my completion handler is not invoked in any way. The control flow leaves my app, goes to Facebook, and then from there (with no user interaction or an intermediatery screen) to Safari. Nothing is hit at my app.